# selecting rows of dataframe where only one value differs from reference

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have made a dataframe where there are all combinations of a set of variables, but I am only interested in the rows where only one of these values differ from a reference set of values.

So if the values of interest are:

```
V1int <- 1
V2int <- 2
V3int <- 3
```

and my dataframe is:

```
df<-data.frame("V1"=c(1,1,2,1), "V2"=c(2,2,2,3), "V3"=c(3,1,3,2))
```

Then I would want the first three rows (c(1,2,3), c(1,2,1), and c(2,2,3)), but not the fourth (c(1,3,2)), because there is only one value out of place in the first three rows, but two out of place in the final row.

I imagine there must be some kind of "or" statement which could generate all the suitable combinations of values that I could then subset the dataframe on, but I'm not sure. I have ten columns and 40,000 combinations of values,so individually specifying the combinations of desired values isn't exactly possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(1:3  == x) >= 2), ]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  2  3
#2  1  2  1
#3  2  2  3
```

where `1:3` is short for `c(V1int, V2int, V3int)`.

The idea is to compare the elements of every row with `1:3` and then check if at least two elements are the same. The result is a logical vector that we use to subset your data.

---

Another option would be

```
df[colSums(t(df) == 1:3) >= 2, ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. This worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Another angle

**sample data**

```
df<-data.frame("V1"=c(1,1,2,1), "V2"=c(2,2,2,3), "V3"=c(3,1,3,2))

V1int <- 1
V2int <- 2
V3int <- 3
```

**code**

```
reference <- c( V1int, V2int, V3int )
df[ apply( df, 1, function(x) length( which( as.vector(x) == reference ) ) ) > 1, ]

#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  1  2  1
# 3  2  2  3
```